# JavaScript Validation Error in my excercise

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develope a e-learning site for kids. It contains an excercise to select the right answer among the given four options,by seeing the clue image. When the kid selects the right answer,the answer changes to green with right.pngimage,while selecting the wrong answer it changes to red with wrong.png image. the problem here is while clicking on the worng answer for second time shows multiple wrong.png images. the image clue for this question is gift.can anybody help me..
My html code is-

```
<ul class="list gift">
            <li>gasp</li>
            <li>gift</li>
            <li>golf</li>
            <li>gust</li>
        </ul>
```

My JavaScript is-

```
$(document).ready(function() 
         {

     //11111111111111
            $('ul.gift li').click(function(e) 
            { 
                correct = "gift";
                needed = $(this).html();

                if(correct==needed){
                    $( e.target ).closest("li").empty();
                    $innercontent = '<li style="color: green;">'+ needed +'<img src="images/right.png"></li>';
                    $( e.target ).closest("li").html($innercontent);

                    }else{
                        $( e.target ).closest("li").empty();
                        $innercontent = '<li style="color: red;">'+ needed +'<img src="images/wrong.png"></li>';
                        $( e.target ).closest("li").html($innercontent);
                        }   

                            });
});
```

Comment: can you put this in js fiddle?

Comment: why are you emptying the closest `li` instead of changing clicked li's style ?

Comment: is that a problem? @ Kola  since am new to Programming,I have tried my best to develope this site..Help me if any corrections needed

Comment: Thanks All for your comments and answers:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your needed variable is causing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/6gkpyhyf/

```
 needed = $(this).text();
```

Change from needed = $(this).html(); to needed = $(this).text();

Comment: Thanks VJS..Exactly what i have expected:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on each click on `li` you append image again and again, event it's already been checked before. So you need a way to know that this element is already clicked and do nothing in this case.

For example you can add additional CSS class. Something like this (with some additional improvements to the code):

```
$('ul.gift li').click(function (e) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('answered')) {
        return;
    }

    var correct = "gift";
    var needed = $(this).html();

    if (correct == needed) {
        var $innercontent = '<img src="images/right.png">';
        $(this).addClass('answered correct').append($innercontent);
    } else {
        var $innercontent = '<img src="images/wrong.png"></li>';
        $(this).addClass('answered wrong').append($innercontent);
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LvrLtchf/

A few notes. 1). Instead of `$( e.target ).closest("li")` you can simply use `$(this)` as in your case this is the same element. 2). Always declare variables with `var` keyword. 3). Instead of inline styles it's more flexible to use classes, e.g. `.right {color: green}` instead of `style="color: green"`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(document).ready(function() 
         {
            $('ul.gift li').click(function(e) 
            { 
                correct = "gift";
                needed = $(this).html();

                if(correct==needed){
     $(this).addClass('correct');
    }else{
     $(this).addClass('incorrect');
    }
});
});
```

```css
ul li {
   background-position: right center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 30px 30px;
   height: 30px;
   width: 100px;
  }
  .correct {
   background-image: url(http://chinagorman.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/check-mark-small.jpg);
   color: green;
  }
  .incorrect {
   background-image: url(https://www.catholicmatri.com/images/wrong-icon.png);
   color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list gift">
            <li>gasp</li>
            <li>gift</li>
            <li>golf</li>
            <li>gust</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just via CSS with less JavaScript is a bit cleaner

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('ul.gift li').click(function () {

        var correct = "gift",
            given = $(this).text();

        $("ul.gift li").removeClass("co in");
        if (correct === given) {
            $(this).addClass("co");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("in");
        }

    });
});

.co:after{
 content:url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1609/ose_png/256/tick.png");
 zoom: .06;

}
.in:after{
  content:url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1014/ivista/128/error.png");
  zoom: .1;
}
li:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/retujikoto/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

This may be a useful general approach for you, helping you keep your code "DRY". Especially if you're set on hardcoding answers as a classname:

**1)** create and cache image to append to answers

**2)** set-up our click handler

**3)** declare vars

**a)** a cache $(this) -- the clicked li

**b)** replace spaces and special chars in text with dashes for easy class names -- note: I think data attributes would be a better way to go.

**c)** determine appropriate image based upon answer correctness

**4)** append updated image to li

[image: Question]

```
$(function() {

  /*1*/
  var $rightWrongImg = $('<img />', { 
    src: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/156843/ex.png' 
  });

  /*2*/
  $('ul.question').on('click', 'li', function(e) {

    /*3*/
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text().replace(/\W+/g, '-'),
        imgSrc = $this.parent().hasClass(text) ? 'right' : 'wrong';

    /*4*/
    $rightWrongImg.attr('src', imgSrc+'.png').appendTo($this);
  });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="question list gift">
  <li>gasp</li>
  <li>gift</li>
  <li>golf</li>
  <li>gust</li>
</ul>
```

this will also work:

```
<ul class="question list longer-answer-with-spaces">
  <li>this is incorrect</li>
  <li>longish and wrong</li>
  <li>longer answer with spaces</li> <!-- win -->
  <li>i am not not wrong</li>
</ul>
```